# How to automatically 'git tag -a' after a pull request has completed on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do we add custom annotated tags on `master` once the pull requests (PR) is complete, **automatically**?

More background:

- Using `azure-pipelines.yml`
- Branch policies on `master` to force PR to be used
- We have a repository that holds Azure Devops Pipeline Templates ("devops templates repo")
- Other repos have a root pipeline file that references the "devops template" repo
- We use SEMVER for tagging our products, including the devops template repo
- In root pipelines we wish to pin to a SEMVER release of the devops template repo
- We currently tag *manually* with each of the following to point to the merge commit that occurred after the PR completed

  - "v`MAJOR`.`MINOR`.`PATCH`"
  - "v`MAJOR`.`MINOR`"
  - "v`MAJOR`"

Pin on `MAJOR` only example:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: template_devops_pipelines
      ref: "refs/tags/v1"
```

Comment: You can consider using this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated%20tags/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in pipeline to create git tags.

Comment: Sounds like we need a tagging pipeline then, because our PR merges don't complete until prod stage is completed.

Comment: If you have configured branch policy, you can create a pipeline(enable the CI) to call the rest api,  it may meet your needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sample tagging pipeline that I use:

```yaml
trigger:
  - main

variables:
  user.email: "devops@myorganization.com" 
  user.name: "DevOps"
  defaultBranch: "main"
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  patch: $[counter(variables['patch'], 2)]

name: $(major).$(minor).$(patch)

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
  - script: |
      git config user.email ${{variables['user.email']}}
      git config user.name ${{variables['user.name']}}
    displayName: 'configure git credentials'
  - script: | 
      git tag "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      git push origin "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
    displayName: 'git tag'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['defaultBranch'])
```

You basically need three things:

1. checkout with `persistCredentials` - so your pipeline can tag and push later
2. configure git user.email and user.password
3. tag & push

For the last step, you will need to assign "Contribute" permissions to pipeline build service account. Go to: `Project Settings -> Repositiories ->  {your repo} -> Security`, find user `{your organization} Build Service` and set Contribute to `Allow`.